# Why do my .d.ts interface extensions not work?

Tags: typescript, material-ui, typescript-typings

I'm having a real battle trying to get `.d.ts` files working properly within a monorepo. What I'm trying to do is extend a material-ui interface and then export that updated type to be consumed in multiple other places.

**types/src/material-ui.d.ts**

```
declare module "@material-ui/core" {
    interface CommonColors {
        amberGreen: string;
        green2: string;
        red2: string;
        yellow2: string;
    }
}
```

**types/src/index.ts**

```
import "./material-ui.d.ts";

export {};
```

I've tried all sorts of ways of importing this though and trawled numerious StackOverflow questions, but I'm unable to make it work. `red2` in my other package is always undefined. Currently I'm using:

**mui-test/src/index.ts**

```
import { useTheme } from "@material-ui/core";
import "@iw/types";

export const useMUITest = (): void => {
    const theme = useTheme();

    console.log(theme.palette);
    console.log(theme.palette.common);
    console.log(theme.palette.common.red2);
};
```

I've a full reproduction of the issue here https://github.com/IPWright83/pnpm-monorepo/tree/d-ts

```
@iw/mui-test:build: src/index.ts(9,38): error TS2339: Property 'red2' does not exist on type 'CommonColors'.
@iw/mui-test:build:  ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 2.
@iw/mui-test:build: ERROR: command finished with error: command (packages/mui-test) pnpm run build exited (1)
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I'm setting up a PNPM monorepo quite similar to yours (I was using this one was reference: https://github.com/spa5k/monorepo-typescript-rust) and I'm having the same issue. It's worth noting that all the code I have comes from a regular repo that works perfectly fine, so somehow PNPM is messing around with the theme extension.

Comment: Just found this, maybe worth taking a look or opening an issue to ask: https://github.com/medtechanalytics/mta-monorepo

Comment: @Danziger I used `pnpm patch` to modify the interface definition in the library itself in the end. Not ideal but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your file `material-ui.d.ts` should first be named `index.d.ts` first.
You should use the `export` keyword also, such as:

```
declare module "@material-ui/core" {
    export interface CommonColors {
        amberGreen: string;
        green2: string;
        red2: string;
        yellow2: string;
    }
}
```

You should also export by default your interface in its definition file, such as:

```
export interface CommonColors {
    amberGreen: string;
    green2: string;
    red2: string;
    yellow2: string;
}
export default CommonColors;
```

Answer (score -1):

First, add a new folder for `@material-ui/core` in your `types/src` directory. Then, move `material-ui.d.ts` to the directory `@material-ui/core/styles` and rename it `createPalette.d.ts`. The contents should look like this:

```js
declare module "@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette" {
    interface CommonColors {
        amberGreen: string;
        green2: string;
        red2: string;
        yellow2: string;
    }
}
```

Then, in `tsconfig.json` add this to your [`typeRoots`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots):

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types",
        "types/src"
    ]
}
```

You don't need to import this module; TypeScript should use it based on what we told it from the config.

Thus, your file tree should look similar to the following:

```
example
│   tsconfig.json
│
├───mui-test
│   └───src
│           index.ts
│
└───types
    └───src
        └───@material-ui
            └───core
                └───styles
                        createPalette.d.ts
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and the clarity on what should be updated where. I've tried this however and I don't think it's working still? I believe I've made the appropriate changes to https://github.com/IPWright83/pnpm-monorepo/tree/pigrammer if you'd like to actually test yourself.

Comment: @Ian I think I see what's wrong. In `mui-test/tsconfig.json`, the path should be `../types/src` instead of just `types/src` because you need to go up one directory. Sorry, I should probably have looked at your specific structure instead of assuming you had one root tsconfig.

Comment: I did actually try that already as I'd guessed that path was wrong, but it didn't help so I assumed it was something else.

Comment: @Ian I don't know what's going on. However, why don't you just use `@types/material-ui`?

Comment: have you tried the sample repo at all? `@types/material-ui` defines the Theme, but it is designed to be extended so you can add your own colours to the palette, which is what I'm trying to do here. It's fully within scope of the use case, I just can't get it working :(

Comment: @Ian sorry. I think it might work now.

Comment: still no dice :( I've updated that branch to reflect your changes. Feel free to fork and demo changes on GitHub if that's easier and we can edit the answer post success :)

Comment: @Ian you should also be updating the name of the module in the declare

Comment: still exactly the same error after updating the module name :( Branch has been updated as usual